# How to get item what been clicked on Chart (primeNg chart + angular application)

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, primeng, bubble-chart

I have bubble chart and I want to call the function with bubble data when I do click on bubble.

How can I pass the data to this function?

[image]

```
<p-chart type="bubble" [data]="chartData" [options]="options" (click)=openProject($event)></p-chart>

  openProject(event) {
    // how I can get item value here?
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeng have given there own method **onDataSelect** to handle click event at official website. You can use that.

```
<p-chart type="line" [data]="data" (onDataSelect)="selectData($event)"></p-chart>

selectData(e:any){
        console.log(e.dataset);
        console.log(e.element);
        console.log(e.element._datasetIndex);
        console.log(e.element._index);
    }
```

I am not sure primeng supports bubble chart. Cause when I passed type as a Bubble. It is not showing anything. I tried above method in line bar etc.